# Inserting data into a Core Data model is unacceptably slow

Tags: swift, core-data

I need to be able to import over 100,000 records on a weekly basis. The data is coming from a web service as a CSV file. Downloading it is fast, as is massaging it into a usable form. However, adding the records to the model works but is unacceptably slow -almost an hour!

I realize I'm saving after each record. There must be a better way to do this.

Please advise or point me to another answer. Here is my working code. Many thanks.

```
func loadDataBase() {

    for i in 1..<objectArray.count - 1 {

        let item: [String] = objectArray[i]


        s_stop_id = Int(item[0])
        s_stop_code = Int(item[1])
        s_stop_name = item[2]

        let mainDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = mainDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let newResource = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: stopEntity, into: context)

        newResource.setValue(s_stop_id, forKey: "stop_id")
        newResource.setValue(s_stop_name, forKey: "stop_name")
        newResource.setValue(s_stop_code, forKey: "stop_code")


        do {
            try context.save()

        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Error While Saving Data: \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

I'm showing some usage information. I appear to be using 100% CPU. Is it feasible to run this process in the background? Then timing won't be so much of an issue..

[image]

Comment: "However, adding the records to the model works but is unacceptably slow."  That expression won't convince anyone that it's indeed slow.

Comment: Ok -edited the question, anything else needed?

Comment: Take mainDelegate and context out of the functions.

Comment: Take newResource out of the function as well.  Or the app can crash.

Comment: Would you mind posting a short example. I have brain melt.

Comment: I'm not going to show you since you are not providing all the pieces of information.

Comment: What am I missing?

Comment: As of me you are inserting data on the main object context. If you want to insert that amount of data you should go to the bulk insertion.

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper, can you please show an example of using bulk insertion?

Comment: Why aren't you saving after the loop? Is this on a Mac -  have you removed the default attached undo manager?

Comment: I'll try saving after the loop again, but I think when I did that, I only saved the last record. Re `undoManager`, isn't that essential? If not, how do I remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should probably instantiate the context and save outside the for, it would be something like this:

```
func loadDataBase() {

    let mainDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = mainDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    for i in 1..<objectArray.count - 1 {

        let item: [String] = objectArray[i]


        s_stop_id = Int(item[0])
        s_stop_code = Int(item[1])
        s_stop_name = item[2]



        let newResource = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: stopEntity, into: context)

        newResource.setValue(s_stop_id, forKey: "stop_id")
        newResource.setValue(s_stop_name, forKey: "stop_name")
        newResource.setValue(s_stop_code, forKey: "stop_code")
    }
    do {
            try context.save()

        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Error While Saving Data: \(error.userInfo)")
        }
}
```

Comment: @all, I've updated my question a bit. Can I perform these data loads on a background thread? It seems that I'm using 100% resources at the moment, so the UI is overwhelmed. Thanks

Comment: I'm marking Eduardo's answer as correct. After I looked again at @Giles's comment, I reworked the contextSave, and now the load is blazing fast - less than 1 minute! Thanks to everyone for the help

Answer (score 2):

Test the following with `autoreleasepool`.

```
let mainDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let newResource = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: stopEntity, into: context)

for i in 1..<objectArray.count - 1 {
    autoreleasepool(invoking: { () -> () in
        let item: [String] = self.objectArray[i]
        s_stop_id = Int(item[0])
        s_stop_code = Int(item[1])
        s_stop_name = item[2]
        newResource.setValue(s_stop_id, forKey: "stop_id")
        newResource.setValue(s_stop_name, forKey: "stop_name")
        newResource.setValue(s_stop_code, forKey: "stop_code")

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Error While Saving Data: \(error.userInfo)")
        }    
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I’ll try asap

Comment: @Eduardo - your solution only saves the last record. @El Tomato, the time is reduced to 16 minutes, but that is still too much. Also, you have `for i in 1..<objectArray.count - 1` shown twice.

Comment: I've fixed the mistake.

Comment: I don't know.  16 minutes kind of sounds reasonable for 100,000 records.